# JPA Define Custom Sort Order (sort by Expression)

Tags: sorting, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Using JPA what are my options for defining an `ORDER BY` statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM schema.table
ORDER BY property = 2822 DESC, property = 3 DESC, property = 1 DESC
```

Currently my product is using JPA repositories, filtering using `Specification`, and sorting (on property name ASC|DESC) within `Pageable`. I read somewhere on SO that I might be able to use JQL... but that would require rewriting a large chunk of a framework we wrote for custom filtering. I'm wondering if I need to be extending `Sort.Order`, `Pageable`, and the dialect or if there is something already built in.

EDIT: Basically I am looking for a way to support sort by expression rather than by a simple property name. Digging into `SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery`

```
    protected <S extends T> TypedQuery<S> getQuery(@Nullable Specification<S> spec, Class<S> domainClass, Sort sort) {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<S> query = builder.createQuery(domainClass);
        Root<S> root = this.applySpecificationToCriteria(spec, domainClass, query);
        query.select(root);
        if (sort.isSorted()) {
            query.orderBy(QueryUtils.toOrders(sort, root, builder));
        }

        return this.applyRepositoryMethodMetadata(this.em.createQuery(query));
    }
```

If I debug and replace the results of `QueryUtils.toOrders` with an Order with an expression, for example, `orders.add(new OrderImpl(cb.equal(from.get("id"), 2), false))` then I believe I am getting the desired SQL. So then I think I just need to figure a way to do that programmatically.

```
    public static List<Order> toOrders(Sort sort, From<?, ?> from, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        if (sort.isUnsorted()) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        } else {
            Assert.notNull(from, "From must not be null!");
            Assert.notNull(cb, "CriteriaBuilder must not be null!");
            List<Order> orders = new ArrayList();
            Iterator var4 = sort.iterator();

            while(var4.hasNext()) {
                Sort.Order order = (Sort.Order)var4.next();
                orders.add(toJpaOrder(order, from, cb));
            }

            return orders;
        }
    }
```